# Constable Grace Note?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, stack-exchange-team

Stack Exchange employee Grace Note appears on the [list of Constable badges for Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/badges/85/constable). They were never a moderator there, neither appointed nor elected. This must be some sort of bug in the badge system. Hopefully it doesn't mean they're leaving SE and their employee bit is being reset?!

Also, the badge shows as having been awarded on 17 Feb 2018, but it definitely wasn't always there. So the date is out as well as the fact that it exists at all.

[image: Screenshot of the badge page, showing Grace Note having earned the Constable badge on Feb 17, 2018]

Comment: [Gabe on Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/85/constable) too.

Comment: There was an event about a month ago where we changed... something and that caused the badge tool to forget to check employee status when awarding badges. It's uncertain to me whether there's any plan to remove the badges. That said, the badge history page does get very confusing so we probably should. What was once a history of all of the long-serving mods on a site is now a bit cluttered.

Comment: I think most of the staff awardees had their staff bits removed, but their moderator bits weren't removed by the time the scripts would run and award them the badge.

Comment: Yaakov has *two* on SO :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek [Three Sheriffs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff?userid=51).

Comment: As pointed out this is a minor bug related to a site change last year. I marked as status-review to see if it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was an issue where staff who had been manually modded before a certain date where mistakenly given the Constable badge on sites. This one was missed with the cleanup.

> extra constable
> badge on literature site
> is no longer there

Comment: Are sheriff badges like [Lisa Park's on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff?userid=16112683) part of this same issue? Also do you have a preference on reporting future cases of these? and is there some wider cleanup effort planned to fix these cases across the network?

Comment: I'll take the answer as "no there is no easy fix to clean up the underlying mess". Grace Note's constable badges on https://iota.stackexchange.com/help/badges/85/ https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/badges/91/constable and 2x https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/274 are still there (and I did not check whether that list is exhaustive)